# Passing a radiobutton value to the textview in android

Tags: android

I have two activities or "screens".

The second activity has an AlertDialogBox with radiobuttons for selecting a single option.

I want that after an option has been selected from the second activity's DialogBox, it should be displayed on the first activity screen in a text-view.

That is, suppose the user chooses "Green" from the dialogbox in the second activity, then "Green" should be displayed on the first activity screen.

Whats the way to pass a radiobuttonvalue to the textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will refer to your first activity (with the `TextView`) as A and the second (with the radio buttons) as B.

Step #1: Have A start B via `startActivityForResult()`

Step #2: When the user clicks on a radio button, B calls `setResult()` to supply the selection to A, then calls `finish()` to return control to A

Step #3: A needs to override `onActivityResult()` to get the results supplied by B